# Convert string with references to variables to variable names in Groovy

Tags: xml, maven, groovy, pom.xml

OK, I have a string with references to variables that looks like this:

`${build.something.name},${build.otherthing.name}`

and I want to get the variable names from it, like so:

`[build.something.name, build.otherthing.name]`

Is there an elegant way this can be done? I know, weird situation to be in, but I have to extract information from a piece of Maven XML file (pom.xml) that looks like this:

`<build.list>${build.something.name},${build.otherthing.name}</build.list> <build.something.name>somename</build.something.name> <build.otherthing.name>anothername</build.otherthing.name>`

using groovy (the XML file is already loaded to a map, build.list can have one or more than one elements, but not none). Also, I need both the key name and key contents.

---

I am currently doing it via string manipulation, like so:

`def names = myString.substring(2, myString.length() - 1).split('},\\$\\{')`

but I was wondering if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

```js
def src='''<build.list>${build.something.name},${build.otherthing.name}</build.list>'''
def varList = src.findAll(/\$\{([^\}]+)\}/){it[1]}

assert varList==['build.something.name', 'build.otherthing.name']
```